# How to apply the chain rule of differentiation when one of the intermediate variables is a multivariable function inside an integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have a function that has the following expression:
$$F(\theta)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_1(f_2(\theta, x), y(x))dx$$

where $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial \theta}$ is well defined at the infinity. So, to calculate $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}$, I can apply the Leibniz integral rule and do
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}=\int \frac{\partial f_1(f_2(\theta, x), y(x))}{\partial \theta}dx
$$
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}=\int \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial f_2}\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \theta} dx.
$$
However, if I were to apply the chain rule first to $F$, I would have
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial f_1}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial f_2}\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \theta}.
$$
I would like to know how I can calculate the expression of $\frac{\partial F}{\partial f_1}$, or does the chain rule not apply to this case? The reason I suspect this is because $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \theta}$ is still dependent of $x$ which in the first method should be traced out by the integral.

Thank you!

Comment: You are passing the derivative through the integral (assuming mild conditions hold that allow it): $$\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(\theta, x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d}{d\theta} h(\theta,x)dx$$ This is similar to differentiating a sum  $$\frac{d}{d\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n h_i(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d}{d\theta} h_i(\theta)$$  Also the chain rule applies to compositions of functions from $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, not for $F:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $D$ the infinite dimensional set of all integrable functions ("type error" between set $D$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: $F$ is a function of the number $\theta$. $F$ isn't a functional of the function $f_1$, so differentiating $F$ wrt $f_1$ isn't correct (unless you really *do* want $F$ to be a functional... )

Comment: Please do not write derivatives of functions with respect to functions. It is sloppy, misleading, and leads to misunderstandings. Write $f_1(u,v)$ and then $u=f_2(x,\theta)$ and $v=y(x)$. Then $f(x,\theta) = f_1(f_2(x,\theta),y(x)$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial u}\Big|_{(f_2(x,\theta,y(x))} \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial\theta}\Big|_{(x,\theta)}.$$

Comment: @Sal This is exactly what I want, to consider $F$ also as a functional of $f_1$. Is it possible to do that in a closed-form expression and then apply the chain rule? Thanks!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the correction on a more rigorous format!

Comment: @FrankWang If you do that, you should search for 'functional derivative chain rule' (I leave open the question of how precisely it would appear in your final expression). The point being: it's not going to result in a `nicer' expression at all. Is there any reason you need to have a chain rule expression?